# Get ARN from AWS Step Functions Activity Name

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

Is there a way to get ARN of a Step Functions "Activity" from the "Name" of the activity using Java? For example, the ARN is in the following format:

arn:aws:states:us-east-1:acct-number:activity:activity-name

Is there an API available that looks something like this:  **getActivityArn(activityName)**

Comment: Of course, this will work but we want to avoid specifying 'account number' in our properties file. DevOps team doesn't like that. Will look into 'listActivities' as suggested by John Rotenstein.

Comment: From inside any EC2 instance (though not from a Lambda function), you can also learn the account number associated with the instance, using the [instance identity document from the instance metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html), e.g. `curl -s -S http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .accountId`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Now do you see how complex your suggestion is? Wouldn't 'listActivities' be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function like that, but you could use [`listActivities()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/stepfunctions/AbstractAWSStepFunctions.html#listActivities-com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.ListActivitiesRequest-), which returns a list of activities including their Name and ARN. You could then filter/iterate the list to extract an ARN given a Name.